Shared folder remounts itself after umount
On a Oracle Linux 7.9 server, I have a directory that is mounted from another system. The fstab entry is:
myuser@192.168.10.2:/opt/commonfiles /opt/commonfiles/ fuse.sshfs identityfile=/home/myuser/.ssh/id_rsa,x-systemd.automount,x-systemd.nofail,_netdev,user,idmap=user,transform_symlinks,default_permissions,allow_other,rw,uid=1004,gid=1004,umask=0003   0 0

I need the ownership set as myuser so that the applications that run on both machines would have suitable rights. This has been working satisfactorily for a number of years.
Now, the server is being replaced by a newer, shinier one; let's call it 192.168.10.3.
I duplicated the fstab line with the second IP, mounted the directory in a temporary path to test, unmounted it. Next, I wanted to umount this, change the pointing and mount to new server.
When I give the command sudo umount /opt/commonfiles I get the bash prompt and no errors or warnings. Similarly, nothing in /var/log/messages. The command df -h shows that it has been unmounted, but only for a few seconds.
But then, it get auto-remounted. If I say sudo umount /opt/commonfiles;sudo mount /opt/commonfiles;df -h, I get the response that directory is not empty and df shows the old server is still mounted even though its fstab entry has been commented out.
Firstly, this is a production server with 24/7 transactions, so there is no time to reboot it unless I wake up in the wee hours to do this.
Secondly, lsof shows no locks on any files within /opt/commonfiles.
It looks to me that the reason is the x-systemd.automount option. Although, it should only mean that the device is to be mounted at boot time.

I think automount is mounting whenever there is an access to the relevant directory

Probably. Commenting it out should have gotten rid of the automount.
